# How to configure ParcelJS for Chrome DevTools extension project

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, panel, parceljs, parcel

I maintain a Chrome DevTools extension for which I utilise Gulp to bundle my code. Since Gulp is not maintained anymore, I am looking to migrate to another bundler. I started a test project to try out Parcel as it has [web extension support](https://parceljs.org/recipes/web-extension/).

- [.parcelrc](https://github.com/temelm/training-parcel-web-extension/blob/main/.parcelrc) file placed in the root directory tells Parcel this is a web extension project.

```
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-webextension"
}
```

- Application entry point can be found at `src/manifest.json`.

```
{
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  },
  "description": "Training Parcel Web Extension",
  "devtools_page": "devtools/devtools.html",
  "icons": {
    "128": "images/logo.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Training Parcel Web Extension",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

- Parcel seems to be able to reference `devtools/devtools.html`. This file loads `devtools/devtools.js` which executes the following:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create(
  'Training Parcel Web Extension',
  '../images/logo.png',
  './panel/index.html'
)
```

- **Everything seems to work except Parcel is unable to resolve `panel/index.html`. Is there a clean way of achieving this?**
- Second problem I have is for some reason I am unable to get Parcel to watch for changes and rebuild the app. I tried the following commands:

```
parcel watch src/manifest.json --host localhost --config @parcel/config-webextension

parcel serve src/manifest.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update using CRXJS instead:** it was complaining about the relative path - removing `./` at line 26 made it work

[image]

[image: I also tried]

---

**Original Answer**

**Why this is happening:** The parcel bundler isn't seeing `./panel/index.html` because nothing is linking or referencing it. So it is ignored and never bundled to your `/dist` folder.

**To fix problem 1**:
update `manifest.json` with reference it as a web resource

```
// manifest.json
...
"web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["devtools/panel/index.html"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
"content_scripts": [],
```

then update the path in `devtool.js` to be the same as the manifest web resource.

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create(
  'Training Parcel Web Extension',
  '../images/logo.png',
  'devtools/panel/index.html'
)
```

This should bundle `panel/index.html` along with anything it might call. Your devtool should load correctly in your popup inspect.

[image: result]
[image: bundle]

**Regarding problem 2**: you didn't post the error you are getting (if any) but I'm guessing it's this one?

```
Server running at http://localhost:1234
 Build failed.

@parcel/transformer-webextension: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'flatMap')
```

If so the fix was adding `"content_scripts": []` to your manifest.json (this is a bug in @parcel/config-webextension that breaks with Mv3 when this field is missing ‍♂️

After that `parcel serve src/manifest.json` should work

Comment: Both problems are resolved after applying your fixes. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that was helpful!

Comment: Since there's no need for `web_accessible_resources` with devtools panels by API design, it must be a bug in Parcel. Note that using this feature makes the extension detectable by web sites.

Comment: @MimiEAM - May I be cheeky and ask the equivalent question for CRXJS? Solution you suggested for Parcel does not seem to work with Vite+CRXJS. I created a new test project for this. https://github.com/temelm/training-crx-vanilla

Comment: @temelm updated! I also did try @wOxxOm's suggestion and while i was able to build your project, the devtool panel was empty. It is worth noting that without  `web_accessible_resources` crxjs did not ignore the file at bundle time, like parcel did. So I wonder if there is maybe another way of loading that file in the devtool panel.. but I'm not too familiar with that.

Comment: @MimiEAM Thanks for that! It's partially working now. `devtools/panel/index.html` loads itself but is unable to load any of its assets (styles, scripts, etc.). I agree with you; I think I need to handle this differently with CRX. I'll investigate when I have some time. On a completely separate note, if you are interested in browser extension development, I came across PlasmoJS which seems promising :)